# How should I setup my input neurons to recieve my input

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network

I need to be able to determine if a shape was drawn correctly or incorrectly,

I have sample data for the shape, that holds the shape and the order of pixels (denoted by the color of the pixel)

for example, you can see of the downsampled image and color variation

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out the network I need to define that will accept this kind of input for training.

should I convert the sampledown image to a matrix and input it? let's say my image is 64x64, I would need 64x64 input neurons (and that's if I ignore the color of the pixels, I think) is that feasible solution?

If you have any guidance, I could use it :)

Comment: Yeah,downsampling is a conventional preprocessing step. If it is just digit recognition, you can even binary the pixel, such that the input is just 16x16 or 64x64 binary features.

Comment: So I should create 64 input neurons, and input one pixel column at at time? If I do care about the color, every pixel input is should be the intensity of the color of that pixel?

Comment: if after down-sampling, you have 64x64, then you have an input vector of 4096 neurons (you need to combine those rows or columns into one 1d array). if you want to keep the intensity of color, e.g., R/G/B, then you have to triple the number of inputs thus the number of neurons become 4096x3. I suggest you further downsample, 16x16 should be enough, which is only 256 neurons at input layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave you an example as below. 
It is a binarized 4x4 image of letter `c`. You can either concatenate the rows or columns. I am concatenating by columns as shown in the figure. Then each pixel is mapped to an input neuron (totally 16 input neurons). In the output layer, I have 26 outputs, the letters `a` to `z`.

Note, in the figure, I did not connect all nodes from layer `i` to layer `i+1` for simplicity, which you probably should connect all.

At the output layer, I highlight the node of `c` to indicate that for this training instance, `c` is the target label. The expected input and output vector are listed in the bottom of the figure.

If you want to keep the intensity of color, e.g., R/G/B, then you have to triple the number of inputs. Each single pixel is replaced with three neurons.

Hope this helps more. For a further reading, I strongly suggest the deep learning tutorial by Andrew Ng at [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Exercise:Sparse_Autoencoder) - [UFLDL](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial). It's the state of art of such image recognition problem. In the exercise with the tutorial, you will be intensively trained to preprocess the images and work with a lot of engineering tricks for image processing, together with the interesting deep learning algorithm end-to-end.

[image]